# Having less code for the current program

Tags: javascript, html5

I am was writing a practice program in javascript and it turned out to work quite alright, however I am not entirely happy with the code. I can't shake the feeling that there is a lot of code which doesn't have to be there, I feel that it can be improved.

The idea of the program is basically, you have a selector, each time you make a choice and hit submit a new set of choices are offered. The choices of the user are stored in an object.

I am interested to know if there is a way to make this code more efficient.

Here is the entire source code (+ the html part)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Dynamic Selector</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="select">
</select>
    <button onclick="updateObject()">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var select = document.getElementById("select");

    var choice = { time: "", category: "", complexity: "" };
    var time = ["15", "30", "60", "60+"];
    var category = ["knowedge", "experimenting", "self-iprovement", "cooking", "health"];
    var complexity = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    var coef = 0;

    //creates the children for the time choices
    function setChoices() {
        if (coef === 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
                var node = document.createElement('option');
                node.value = time[i].toString();
                node.innerHTML = time[i];
                select.appendChild(node);
            }
        } else if (coef === 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
                var node = document.createElement('option');
                node.value = category[i].toString();
                node.innerHTML = category[i];
                select.appendChild(node);
            }
        } else if (coef === 2) {
            for (var i = 0; i < complexity.length; i++) {
                var node = document.createElement('option');
                node.value = complexity[i].toString();
                node.innerHTML = complexity[i];
                select.appendChild(node);
            }
        }
    }

        function updateObject() {
            if (coef === 0) {
                choice.time = select.value;
                console.log(choice.time);
                coef++;
                removeChildren();
                setChoices();
            } else if (coef === 1) {
                choice.category = select.value;
                coef++;
                removeChildren();
                setChoices();
            } else if (coef === 2) {
                choice.complexity === select.value;
                printObject();
                setChoices();
            }
        }

        //removes the children of the "select" element
        function removeChildren() {
            while (select.firstChild) {
                select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
            }
        }

        function printObject() {
            console.log("foobarr");
        }

        removeChildren();
        setChoices();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the good ol' **DRY** principle and by adding `coef` as a parameter, we'd get something like :

```
function setChoices(coef) {
    var relevantArray = (coef === 0) ? time :
                        (coef === 1) ? category :
                                       complexity;
    for (var i = 0; i < relevantArray.length; i++) {
        var node = document.createElement('option');
        node.value = relevantArray[i].toString();
        node.innerHTML = relevantArray[i];
        select.appendChild(node);
    }
}

function updateObject() {
       for (var coef = 0; coef<3; coef++)
       {
           ((coef === 0) ? choice.time :
            (coef === 1) ? choice.category :
                           choice.complexity) =  select.value;
            removeChildren();
            setChoices(coef);
       }
}
```

(Also, I have changed a few things which I assumed to be wrong, for instance, `updateObject` did not call `setChoices` with `coef=0`.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand this: You are creating a new array(and using it later on) containing the data of one of the 3 arrays, depending on the value of 'coef' right ?

Comment: That's the idea indeed but it shouldn't create a new array, it should just decide at the beginning the one we are going to use afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious change I would recommend is to refactor the for loop in `setChoices`. You're using the same code three times.

Keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

I'd write it somehow like this:

```
// It's better not to rely on globals but to pass them to your functions
// (easier to test)
function updateSelectWithItems(select, arrItems) {
    // It's always a good habit to validate your arguments
    if (!arrItems || arrItems.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("ArgumentNullException: 'arrItems' is null or has no items.")
    }

    if (!select) {
        throw new Error("ArgumentNullException: 'select' is null.")
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {
        var node = document.createElement('option');
        node.value = arrItems[i].toString();
        node.innerHTML = arrItems[i];
        select.appendChild(node);
    }
}

//creates the children for the time choices
function setChoices() {
    switch (coef) {
        case 0:
            updateSelectWithItems(mySelect, time);
            break;
        case 1:
            updateSelectWithItems(mySelect, category);
            break;
        case 2:
            updateSelectWithItems(mySelect, complexity);
            break;
        default:
            // shouldn't happen
            throw new Error("'coef' has a wrong value.");
            break;
    }
}
```